# filter requests based on path using ARR w/ IIS 7.5, on the site level

Tags: iis, arr

I've got two sites configured on different ports, one for public and one for trusted connections.

I've got filters on URLs within the ARR settings, for some internal URLs that shouldn't be proxied at all.

I'd like to be able to block requests to certain URLs at the site level, rather than at the ARR level. Is there a way to achieve this? Is this usually done with site-level request filtering?